Each member of the union type **** has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other
I'm working on a TypeScript project where I have two types, Device and Station, which share common methods. I want to use a union type for a property device, which can be either a Device or a Station.
However, when I try to access a method common to both types, TypeScript raises an error:
This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '(<U extends keyof DeviceEvents>(event: U, listener: DeviceEvents[U]) => Device) | (<U extends keyof StationEvents>(event: U, listener: StationEvents[U]) => Station)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
It works with public device: any but how can I properly define the types or handle the union type so that TypeScript recognizes the on method when using the union type? I've tried using type guards like if ('on' in this.device) but still encounter the same error.
export abstract class BaseAccessory extends EventEmitter {

  constructor(
    public readonly platform: EufySecurityPlatform,
    public device: Device | Station,
  ) {
    super();

    this.device = device as Device | Station;

    if (this.platform.config.enableDetailedLogging) {
      this.device.on('raw property changed', this.handleRawPropertyChange.bind(this));
      this.device.on('property changed', this.handlePropertyChange.bind(this));
    }
  }
}

I've tried using type guards but still encounter the same error.
    if (this.platform.config.enableDetailedLogging) {
      if ('on' in this.device) {
        this.device.on('raw property changed', this.handleRawPropertyChange.bind(this));
        this.device.on('property changed', this.handlePropertyChange.bind(this));
      }
    }

Full code here : https://github.com/homebridge-eufy-security/plugin/blob/v2.3.30/src/plugin/accessories/BaseAccessory.ts

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that doesn't depend on third party or external or private code (unless your question cannot be asked without reference to such code).
